# Unable to cite from a bib file

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I've been trying to cite a single reference, but I cannot solve this issue.
I have cropped the `econometria.tex` file at its minimum:

**Case 1 (chicago)**

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier} 


\begin{document}
Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}
%\bibliographystyle{named}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{./library}
\end{document}
```

I did the same with `library.bib`:

```
@article{evans_dynamic_2010,
    title = {Dynamic news effects in high frequency Euro exchange rates},
    volume = {20},
    issn = {10424431},
    url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S1042443110000053},
    doi = {10.1016/j.intfin.2010.03.002},
    pages = {238--258},
    number = {3},
    journaltitle = {Journal of International Financial Markets, Institutions and Money},
    author = {Evans, Kevin P. and Speight, Alan E.H.},
    urldate = {2018-03-06},
    date = {2010-07},
    langid = {english},
}
```

When I run PDFLatex, I get three error messages .
The first two error messages are duplicated and correspond to line 11 (`Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}`).

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\b@evans_dynamic_2010 ->\citeauthoryear
{Evans and Speight}{Evans and Speigh...
l.11 Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\b@evans_dynamic_2010 ->\citeauthoryear
{Evans and Speight}{Evans and Speigh...
l.11 Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
(./econometria.bbl

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citeauthoryear
{Evans and Speight}{Evans and Speight}{}
l.4 Speight}{}]{evans_dynamic_2010}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
) [1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./econometria.aux) )
```

**Case 2 (named)**

If I change the bibliography style to this:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier} 


\begin{document}
Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}
\bibliographystyle{named}

%\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{./library}
\end{document}
```

If I run the normal cicle PDFLatex -> bibtex ->PDFLatex,
I can compile the tex file, but the citation is not added i.e. the pdf file shows the text

```
Cite: [?]
```

this cycle also shows some messages.

When I run PDFLatex:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `evans_dynamic_2010' on page 1 undefined on input line
11.
(./econometria.bbl) [1
{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./economet
ria.aux)
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
)
```

When I run bibtex:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017) The top-level auxiliary file: econometria.aux I couldn't open style file named.bst ---line 3 of file econometria.aux : \bibstyle{named : } I'm skipping whatever remains of this command I found no style file---while reading file econometria.aux (There were 2 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)
```

**Some extra info**

```
tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=tex)

pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.

bibtex --version
BibTeX 0.99d (TeX Live 2017)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
```

> **EDIT 1**

I kept trying with different approaches, but the errors persist.

**Case 3 (ieeetr)**

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier} 

\begin{document}
Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

When I run bibtex, I get this error:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017) The top-level auxiliary file: econometria.aux The style file: ieeetr.bst I found no \bibdata command---while reading file econometria.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "evans_dynamic_2010" (There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)
```

**Case 4 (abbrvnat)**

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}


\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{courier} 

\begin{document}
Cite: \cite{evans_dynamic_2010}

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat} 
\end{document}
```

the same happens here:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2017) The top-level auxiliary file: econometria.aux The style file: abbrvnat.bst I found no \bibdata command---while reading file econometria.aux Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "evans_dynamic_2010" (There was 1 error message)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> bibtex -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Many of those styles have specific requirements in your .bib or usepackages e.g. biblatex-chicago has a mandatory need for year= (and that wont work on its own) its best to read the user manual for the one style you need or stick to {plain} or look at inline citations like [this example]( https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/simplified-apa6-style-manuscript-how-to-make-basic-citations/bfrbhzvbgqtr)

Answer (score 1):

I thought the problem was associated to texlive configuration, but this problem seems to be related to Texmaker; after installing Texstudio, I was able to compile with the bibliographies without any problem.
I know this does not solve the issues with Texmaker, but I'm fine using Texstudio.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. Pressing F11 seems to activate the bibtex and then my references are recognized. Hope this helps.

Comment: Even though this question is tagged as `texmaker`, you could maybe add this as a hint to your answer, so that people do not think this is a universal solution.